# Class path resourse [ApplicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: maven, java, intellij-idea, resources

Добрый вечер.

Просидел 7 часов в попытке решить эту проблему. Прошу вашей помощи.

Написал небольшое веб-приложение - `Hibernate+Spring+Vaadin`. `ApplicationContext.xml` лежит в папке `src/resourses`. Если его собирать в IDEA из родной директории, где я его писал, - все стартует отлично. Если перенести в другое место и собрать war уже там - он не может найти этот файл (через какое-то время, после 3-й, 4-й сборки запускается нормально, без внесения изменений, что раздражает больше всего).

Для переменной использую

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Собираю проект через Maven. Может, для веб-проектов нужно ресурсы помещать в другую папку или каким-то образом задавать class path? Пробовал переместить в WEB-INF, в src/, но все без толку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать и почему оно то запускается как надо, то не запускается без внесения изменений?

Comment: Некрокомментарий: а не нужно ли файл указывать как `classpath:applicationContext.xml`? Пушо в текущем варианте оно смотрит в текущую рабочую директорию, насколько понимаю, а она может оказаться любой.

Comment: @Etki, не. он и так тащит только из classapath-а.

Answer (score 1):

У вас точно нет опечатки в `src/resourses`? Т. к. стандартная директория с ресурсами в мавене -- `src/resources`.

Ещё стоит глянуть в строчку запуска в идее (которая выводится в консоль) и внимательно поглядеть на то, какой там classpath. Ну и, собирая `mvn clean package` посмотреть, что лежит в получившемся war.